# Determine all $n$ such that $K_n$ decomposes into spanning trees.

Tags: graph-theory

My task asks for the decomposition of the complete graphs on $n$ vertices. I figured out that $n$ must be even but I am not sure how do I prove this? Is induction the only way?

Comment: No, induction is completely unnecessary to prove that $n$ must be even: you need only count the number of edges in $K_n$ and the number of edges in a spanning tree.

Comment: @ErickWong well $K_n$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges while a spanning tree has $n-1$ edges, but how does this help?

Comment: How many spanning trees would be needed to cover all the edges of $K_n$?

Comment: Is it $\frac{n}{2}$?@ErickWong

Comment: Are you actually asking whether you have divided correctly? :)

Comment: @ErickWong of course not. I just wanted to know if this is the correct answer. So we need $n$ to be even because it should be divisible by 2?

Comment: Just think it through: in order to decompose the edges of $K_n$ into spanning trees, the number of spanning trees must be an integer.

Comment: thanks! @ErickWong

Comment: Note that this is only half the answer: this establishes the need for $n$ to be even, but you still need to show that if $n$ is even then there really is a way to decompose $K_n$ into $n/2$ spanning trees.  It's likely that there are several possible constructions that achieve this.

Comment: @ErickWong yes for that part it is okay. I was having trouble with the construction because I already knew that $n$ is even.